# Indexed addressing in x86 assembly - is something like mov array[ebx],eax a valid instruction?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

My understanding is that indexed addressing essentially produces an address whose offset is the number in the brackets.  Is this understanding correct?  But I also understand that this address is dereferenced somehow.  I don't understand exactly how this works.  The book *Assembly Language for Intel-Based Computers* shows a lot of instructions of the form `mov reg,array[reg]` that move data from an indexed array element into a register.  But I need a way to move data back from the register into the array.  How can I do this?  Do I use the opposite of that, which would be `mov array[reg],reg`?  Or would this dereference `array[reg]` and move the data into the address given by the value stored in that array element?

For example, suppose the array index is 3 and it's stored in register EBX, and I want to move the value stored in EAX into that array element.  The value currently stored in that array element is 500 hex.  If I use the instruction `mov array[ebx],eax`, will this instruction move the value in EAX into array[3], or will it move it into memory location 500 hex?  And if it's the latter case, what instruction can I use to avoid this effect and do what I actually want to do, which is move the data into array[3]?

Note: The syntax I am using is for MASM.  I do not have MASM installed on my machine, and it's not really an option since I'm using Ubuntu.  But the book I'm reading is written for MASM, so I'm learning MASM first, just to get a feel for how x86 assembly language works.  I'm not assembling any programs, but I'd like to understand them.

Comment: Because I don't have MASM installed.

Comment: You can't install something like MASM in DOSBox, though.  It would require you to insert disks into drive A and drive B, which you can't do in DOSBox, for obvious reasons.  Sure, you can use the mount command, but you would need some way to suspend the currently running installer, which DOSBox doesn't provide.

Comment: You can install the dos versions of MASM and LINK into dosemu and have them run. I do it here on Debian/dosemu . This may give you an idea how http://itsitrc.blogspot.com/2013/01/assemble-link-and-debug-assembly.html . You can get MASM off the internet in ZIP format. You can just extract much of the MASM directory into your host environment and then mount it to a drive in the virtual dos environment.

Comment: Nobody can learn assembler without trying it out practically. Without, you can learn and memorize what the individual instructions do, but you will never get a feeling for how to make them interact in a way you need to solve problems you didn't see solved before.

Comment: Here is what I recommend. Turbo Assembler is for the most part is MASM compatible (it takes MASM) syntax. There is a [sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tasmforwindows/)  that you can install in DosBox or DosEmu . It can target 32 bit dos applications (using a dos extender) to experiment with 32 bit code. You'd have to run the installer on Windows and then copy the TASM directories to your Ubuntu box. I installed TASM that way here and it does work. Sure you have to find a Windows box, get the files extracted then ZIP up the directory and copy it to Ubuntu.

Comment: I've temporarily made an archive of the TASM files from that sourceforge project that can be extracted to a Ubuntu directory and then mapped into a Dosbox or Dosemu environment. The archive (half a megabyte) is [here](http://www.capp-sysware.com/downloads/tasm.tgz)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That will be very helpful.

Comment: `Do I use the opposite of that` - yes, exactly.